# Why does a nested element of display table-cell show over a higher outer element?

Tags: html, css

I have an element that's nested inside an element of `z-index: 0` that is underneath an element of `z-index: 1`. That parent element *does correctly** show under the other element. But, when I make the child element `display: table-cell; z-index: 2` it jumps out of it's parent (on a vertical z axis) and above the higher, outer element! Why does this happen and how do I stop it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5x8jy74o/
Example with parent as `display: table`, same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/5x8jy74o/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="hover">
HOVER IN HERE
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tc">
    This should be under
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.tc
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to the fact that the element has a `display` of `table-cell`.

It's because the `.container` element isn't actually [establishing a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Despite the fact that the `.container` element is relatively positioned, it still has a default `z-index` of `auto`, not `0`.

If you want to establish a stacking context, and prevent the child element from appearing above the previous sibling, add `z-index: 0`. Otherwise `.tc` will continue appearing above `.hover` because a `z-index` of `2` is clearly higher than `1`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/arys4Ldg/)

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;

  /* .. */
}
```

Comment: It's also important to note that `display: table-cell;` doesn't have anything to do with the stacking here. Removing it and leaving the `z-index` property works just the same: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x8jy74o/2/).

Comment: Than you, this was the issue! I forgot to give a z-index to the container.